# maximum of a function on a specified domain in iPython

Tags: numpy, scipy, ipython, max

I am trying to find the maximum of the following function for 1 < R < 20.  How can I implement this into the code?

The solution is supposed to be R is approx 15.5 or so.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#  Plotting the energy for circular Hohmann transfer

import scipy
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pylab


def f(R):
    return 1 / np.sqrt(R) - (np.sqrt(2) * (1 - R)) / (np.sqrt(2) * (1 + R)) - 1

x = np.arange(1, 20)
pylab.plot(x, f(x), 'r')
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scipy.optimizie.fmin`:

```
>>> scipy.optimize.fmin(lambda r: -f(r), 10)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -0.134884
         Iterations: 16
         Function evaluations: 32
array([ 11.44451904])
```

Which is where the maximum actually is:

```
>>> x = np.linspace(1, 20, 1000)
>>> plt.plot(x, f(x))
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x0000000007BAEF98>]
>>> plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I saw the plot and was wary of the max at 15 but that is what the professor wrote.

Comment: @Jamie I was given the following error:  Traceback (most recent call last):
  5   File "./hw7problem5.py", line 14, in <module>
  6     scipy.optimize.fmin(lambda r: 1/f(r), 10)
  7 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'optimize'

Comment: @dustin You need to import the `optimize` module: `import scipy.optimize`. @Jaime, it would be better to take the opposite of `f` instead of taking the reciprocal. It doesn't matter in this example, but maximizing `f` is the same as minimizing `-f`, not `1/f` in general.

Comment: @jorgeca It had a funny feeling while I was writing it, you are very right indeed, will edit.