# optimize in scipy iPython error

Tags: optimization, scipy, ipython

After help from Jamie on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15754637/maximum-of-a-function-on-a-specified-domain-in-ipython#), I know I need to use scipy.optimize.  However, I keep receiving the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./hw7problem5.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(max_R)
NameError: name 'max_R' is not defined


#!/usr/bin/env python
#  Plotting the energy for circular Hohmann transfer

import scipy
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pylab


def f(R):
    return ((1 / np.sqrt(R)) - ((np.sqrt(2) * (1 - R)) / (np.sqrt(2)
        * (1 + R))) - 1)
    max_r = scipy.optimize.fmin(lambda r: 1 / f(r), 20)

x = np.arange(1, 25, 0.001)
pylab.plot(x, f(x), 'r')
pylab.show()

print(max_R)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to due the job and output the correct solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#  Plotting the energy for circular Hohmann transfer

import scipy
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import pylab
from scipy.optimize import fmin


def f(R):
    return ((1 / np.sqrt(R)) - ((np.sqrt(2) * (1 - R)) / (np.sqrt(R
        * (1 + R)))) - 1)

x = np.arange(1, 20, .001)
max_r = fmin(lambda r: 1.0 / f(r), 20)

pylab.plot(x, f(x), 'r')
pylab.show()

print(max_r)
```

Answer (score 1):

`max_R` should be `max_r`. Python is case-sensitive.

You also aren't storing the result of your function anywhere:

```
x = np.arange(1, 25, 0.001)
max_r = f(x)

pylab.plot(x, max_r, 'r')
pylab.show()

print(max_r)
```

Comment: my output window is only showing: [  0.00000000e+00   1.24812711e-07   4.98503368e-07 ...,   1.23080047e-01
   1.23079006e-01   1.23077965e-01]
Is there anyway I expand the output display?

Comment: @dustin: You'd have to iterate over them with a `for` loop and print each one out individually.

Comment: then is there anyway just to return the one single r value that is the max instead of an array?

Comment: the last line should read then print(numpy.amax(max_r))?  The value it is returning is wrong though: 0.13